# django: how to use many-to-many relationships in values()?

Tags: django

i need to group results by a field that requires a few joins from the original model:

```
// response_filter_args is created dynamically
responses = Response.objects.filter(**response_filter_args) \
        .values('customer__tags__tag') \                  # django doesn't like this
        .annotate(average_score=Avg('rating__score'))
```

Response -> customer -> tags (many-to-many field pointing to Tag) -> tag (the tag as a string)

Models are:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    ...

class Customer(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    ...

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

i'm trying to calculate average ratings. to make it work i need to tell django to group by 'tag', but it refuses to. it gives an error:

```
Invalid field name: 'customer__tags__tag'
```

anyone know how i can get it to group by tag? i've tried all the combinations of underscores in customer_*tags*_tag that i can think of, but nothing works.

Comment: It's hard to tell without your model, but if you have a tags field in your Customer model, then just reference that `.values(customer__tags)`

Comment: customer__tags doesn't work either. i've added my models to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out [the Django docs for values()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) you will see that many to many field support has only been added in the development version and [not in 1.2](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#values):

> The values() method previously [pre dev version] did not return anything for ManyToManyField attributes and would raise an error if you tried to pass this type of field to it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this will work, since django can't get objects that are related via a ManyToMany-relation with one query.